# Can you do this to find circumference from area of a circle

Tags: geometry

If you divide the circumference by $2$, does it equal the area divided by the radius?  That is, do you have

> $C/2 = A/r$

for any circle?

Comment: Yes, both are $\pi r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  $$ \frac{C}{2} = \frac{2 \pi r}{2} = \pi r.$$

Similarly, $$\frac{A}{r} = \frac{\pi r^2}{ r} = \pi r.$$

Answer (score 1):

A good way to view this intuitively is to imagine a circle to be composed of small rings.

Now unroll the rings all the rings into a flat surface, you get a triangle of base $C = 2\pi r$ and height $r$ so area $A=\frac{Cr}{2}$